# HTML img src returning a 404 not found error despite everything in order v.2

Tags: python, flask

I can access the IMG folder from the browser, caps and everything checked. Although when I run python main.py or Heroku app shows 404. I don´t know why it keeps showing 404, I´ve tried every path possible it´s just not working.
I´m using Flask
[app folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZ2I.png)

```
<nav class="nav-main">
            <img src="../img/uiyou.png" alt="logo" class="nav-brand">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#destorni"><img src="../img/destornillador.png" alt="destornillador"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#clean"><img src="../img/reciclar.png" alt="reciclar"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#build"><img src="../img/aerosol-de-limpieza.png" alt="aerosol-de-limpieza"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#buy"><img src="../img/carrito-de-compras.png" alt="carrito-de-compras"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-menu-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </nav>
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:44] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:44] "[33mGET /src/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/2.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/extra.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/pcv31.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/pcv23.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/pcv22.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /src/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /img/uiyou.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /images/destornillador.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /img/reciclar.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /img/aerosol-de-limpieza.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /img/carrito-de-compras.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /img/unnamed.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/aaaaaa.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:45] "[33mGET /templates/ffffffffffff.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:46] "[33mGET /img/favicon/manifest.json HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:51] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:51] "[33mGET /src/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/extra.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/2.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/pcv23.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/pcv31.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/pcv22.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /src/static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/uiyou.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /images/destornillador.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/reciclar.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/aerosol-de-limpieza.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/carrito-de-compras.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/unnamed.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/aaaaaa.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /templates/ffffffffffff.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2020 20:57:52] "[33mGET /img/favicon/manifest.json HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6hLd.png)

[access the folder from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzwKI.png)

[Live Server-VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9ey.png)

I notice a difference when I run the app, the port, from 5000 to 5500 as shown in the pictures, but I don't think that is a problem

Comment: You need to add more information to your question. What framework are you using? (i.e. `Flask`, `Django`, etc.)

Comment: I´m using Flask

Comment: _“I can access the IMG folder from the browser”_ - you are accessinjg your folder via the file system there in that second screenshot, that is something completely different, than access via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url_for function.
For example, for the first img, you can do the following

```
<img src="{{ url_for('img', filename='uiyou.png') }}" alt="logo" class="nav-brand">
```

Comment: I´m trying but it shows this:    werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'img' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'home' instead?